# Exporting Blender smoke simulation

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm new to the Blender world. I've created a simple smoke simulation that I'd like to export and import into Keyshot. Is it possible to export the animated smoke as an alembic file?  Under Smoke Domain, I have "baked all dynamics". But when I export the .abc file Keyshot says it's empty and file size is tiny.

What am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Wayne